# How to evaluate the likelihood of a conditional MAXENT estimation?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, conditional-probability, information-theory, maximum-entropy

Suppose I have a random variable $Y$ (the outcome) and a set of random variables $\mathbf{X}$ (the input variables). I don't have access to observations of the joint distribution of $P(Y, \mathbf{X})$, but instead I have statistical moments of them, that is, I have some functions $\phi_{i}(Y, \mathbf{X})$, which depend on some or all variables. For example, I can have the unconditional and bivariate conditional means of $Y$ given each $X$ in $\mathbf{X}$.

Now suppose that I use this information to estimate the parameters of a distribution via the Conditional Maximum Entropy (MAXENT) principle. That is, I find the parameters $\theta$, that maximize the conditional Shannon Entropy, using the statistical moments $\phi_{i}$ as constraints in the estimation.

We now that maximum likelihood (MLE) and MAXENT are dual (see for example Wainwright and Jordan 2008). Meaning (if I am correct) that using the statistical moments $\phi_{i}$, we can evaluate the likelihood of our model parameters. However, it is not entirely clear to me how to do this in the conditional setting. We know that the likelihood can be written as: $\langle\theta, \phi\rangle - \log\sum_{Y}\exp(\langle\theta, \phi\rangle)$. The first term (if I am correct) should be a single value, while the last term, depends on $\mathbf{X}$ and should be of the size of all possible combinations of $\mathbf{X}$.

How can I calculate the likelihood of the parameters estimated via MAXENT ($\hat{\theta_{i}}$) conditioned on the statistics used to estimate them?

Comment: Maxent is a method for constructing a distribution that maximise entropy relative to a particular measure, subject to definite constraints. Why are you using it to estimate the parameters in a given distribution?

Comment: Thank you for your interest and answer @innisfree, I am not using it to estimate the parameters in a given distribution, however, when you do MAXENT you do get a resulting distribution which, as you said, maximises the entropy. See, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution . Now, with an unconditional distribution, it is straightforward to compute the likelihood using the sufficient statistics, it is not clear (at least to me), though, how to do it in conditional MAXENT models.